# Custom UIBarButtonSystemItem with another text

Tags: c#, ios, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

I want an `UIBarButonSystemItem` with another text (similar to e.g. `UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel`) on my bottom toolbar.

This is what I have now (Code is in C# but it doesn't matter because you could provide your solution in Objective-C):

```
UILabel markLabel = new UILabel (new RectangleF(0,0,150,30));
markLabel.Text = "Mark";
UIView containerView = new UIView (new RectangleF(0,0,150,30));
containerView.AddSubview (markLabel);
var markButton = new UIBarButtonItem (markLabel);
```

How should such a button be created? Using an `UIButton` (I failed here) or an `UIView` with `UILabel` as above? Also I have always to provide the *frame*  properties. What is if you want to use Auto-Layout? How can the size be adapted to changing content size (e.g. internationalization) and what about the spacing element?

**Edit:**

This now works with `UIButton`:

```
var temp = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.System);
temp.SetTitle ("Mark", UIControlState.Normal);
temp.SizeToFit ();
var markButton = new UIBarButtonItem (temp);
```

But the color and font size has to be adapted. Some problem still remains: If the text gets wider it doesn't shrink the font size even `AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` is used. Also the positioning is different. E.g. the cancel button has a different spacing to the border of the screen than my button.

Answer (score 1):

A button can be made using `UIButton` like this:

```
UIButton button = new UIButton (new RectangleF(5, 5, 30, 30));
button.SetTitle ("Hello, world", UIControlState.Normal);
```

In this example, the frame properties are hard-coded. If you want to make sizes auto-adjustable, you should add properties to a class that can be called from any other class (like the AppDelegate).

```
public static float ScreenWidth { get; set; }
public static float ScreenHeight { get; set; }
```

Then, add a call to the new properties in the `ViewWillAppear` of the first view that will appear on your screen (and update frame sizes afterwards), and in the `ViewDidRotate` method in all classes where you want controls to be auto-adjustable (and also update frame sizes afterwards):

```
public override void DidRotate (UIInterfaceOrientation fromInterfaceOrientation)
{
    base.DidRotate (fromInterfaceOrientation);

    AppDelegate.ScreenWidth = this.View.Bounds.Width;
    AppDelegate.ScreenHeight = this.View.Bounds.Height;

    UpdateFrameSize ();
}
```

Fontsize can be altered with the `button.Font` property:

```
button.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize (12);
```

Sadly, there's no option to wrap text in a button. If you want text to be displayed and wrapped to fit the screen, you should use a `UILabel` next, above or beneath the button that will display the text you want to display. You can use the `UILabel.Lines` and `UILabel.LineBreakMode` properties of an UILabel.

```
    lblClient.Lines = 5;
    lblClient.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
```

Experiment a bit with these properties and methods, and see what fits best to your project. If something is not clear, or you wish some more explanation on the problems in your example, don't hesitate to ask. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Magicbjørn for your answer. I got it managed to use the solution I posted in my edit. `AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` and `SizeToFit` doesn't work together. You can only use one. With the spacing I took a trick by using a negative spacer. But in this way I don't have to track the screen sizes. But it is nice to have second backup option.